# Sending Automated Email from Access VBA through Outlook

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook-2010

Ok, so I've been putting band aids on top of band aids on a simple snippet of code to get an email to send.  What I've been trying to do is get an email to send through outlook.  My first issue was `runtime object define 287` at the following line:

```
Set appOutlookRec = appOutlookMsg.Recipients.Add
```

so to counter that I added:

```
Set objNS = appOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

And that stopped that.  Now the email will form and I can use `.display` to see my email, but when I try and use `.send` the instance of Outlook closes before the email is actually sent.

To counter that I force outlook to open, but I would like to check if an instance is already open.  To open the inbox I use:

```
Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNS = appOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
olFolder.Display
```

Am I over complicating the automation process?  Or am I on the right path and someone can help checking if an instance of Outlook is open in the explorer window?

Thanks

**Update**

```
Const olMailItem = 0
Const olTo = 1
Const olCC = 2
Const olFolderInbox = 6
Dim appOutlook As Object
Dim appOutlookMsg As Object
Dim appOutlookRec As Object
Dim objNS As Object
Dim olFolder As Object

Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNS = appOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
olFolder.Display

'Create a new empty email message
Set appOutlookMsg = appOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With appOutlookMsg
Set appOutlookRec = appOutlookMsg.Recipients.Add("....@gmail.com")
    appOutlookRec.Type = olTo
    .Subject = "Testing Closed Tickets"
    .Body = "This is just a test."
    '.Display
    .Send
End With

Set appOutlookMsg = Nothing
Set appOutlook = Nothing
Set appOutlookRec = Nothing
```

Comment: Did you try `.Save` the email before `.Send`?

Comment: Good (but strange) news! Outlook is the only Office app where `= CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` will create an instance if it does not exist **OR** use the existing instance, if Outlook is already running.

Comment: Can you post your entire code please?  Are you running this code from Outlook or another source (I'm assuming MS Access)? You can make life a lot easier by referencing the Outlook runtime library in Access

Comment: I was going to mention that @tbur I thought I read that elsewhere but was trying to verify :)  This is also true for PowerPoint.

Comment: @DavidZemens that worked perfectly.  Now I don't have to use `olFolder.Display` to open the instance in explorer.  If you would like to actually write that as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @enderland please see the update.  I didn't want to use a library reference incase someone running a lesser version tries to open the program.  I've run into that issue already between XP and Win7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered something similar before and I think usually you can avoid the error by saving the email prior to sending:

```
appOutlookMsg.Save
appOutlookMsg.Send
```